# SortBy feature does not sort the products in asc or desc

Tags: reactjs, sorting, algolia, react-instantsearch

I am trying to implement a sortBy feature from the Algolia widget, and I can't make the function work

```
 <InstantSearch searchClient={searchClient} indexName="guitar">
            <div className="right-panel">
              <SortBy
                defaultRefinement="guitar"
                items={[
                  { value: 'guitar', label: 'Featured' },
                  { value: 'guitar_price_asc', label: 'Price asc.' },
                  { value: 'guitar_price_desc', label: 'Price desc.' },
                ]}
              />
              <Stats />
            </div>
```

The featured value works, but the others do not.

Comment: Did you setup replicas for `guitar_price`?

Comment: Did you managed to fix your issue?

Comment: I have same problem. I tried all configs but still now showing anything. It's difficult to use